# Card Game in C. Data types rounding to give incorrect results

Tags: c, pointers, types

I am working on an assignment that requires the use of arrays to make a card game similar to war. I have a custom function which is meant to determine the suite of the randomly selected card. It firstly determines the random number and divides that number by 13 (52 cards / 13 cards per suite). If the result is from 0-1 the suite is hearts, from 1-2 is Diamonds, 2-3 is Clubs, and 3-4 is spades.

The issue is that I cannot get a suite to be spades. The result must be rounding so that it can never be from 3-4. I am sure that my data types are incorrect but I am not sure how to fix this.

This is one of my first times posting to this site so any constructive criticism on the format of my question is appreciated.

[The random number is generated in a previous function and it of pointer type int* r](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FhX62.jpg)

Comment: War is a card game. Highest card wins

Comment: Please share your code so someone can help you.

Comment: Rounding? Divide `int` card number `0..51` by 13. `suit = card / 13`. Result 0: hearts, 1: diamonds, 2: clubs, 3: spades. The rank is `card % 13`.

Comment: I posted a screenshot of the function of interest in the original post

Comment: The main problem is that everything is defined as an int--you should use floating point math if you don't want to round down immediately. Use float or double, and then cast to int.

Comment: "War is a card game" - Which can only be stated by someone who never saw what it does to the people involved in real war. Sorry, I'll leave it at that!

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.

Comment: Your code needs to be in the question, preferably as a **minimal, verifiable working example**.

Answer (score 1):

You have this problem because you are trying to get a decimal by dividing an int by and int, neither of which have decimals. Both *r and 13 are integers, and thus their division will result in an integer.

What I would do is instead

```
carda = *r % 4
```

However, I am having a lot of trouble deciphering what the logic behind your line 80 is. I would say

```
int ace = 0, two = 1, three = 2, ....;
```

and I would change your line 78 to be

```
int diamond = 0, heart = 1, club = 2, spade = 3;
```

In CS we like to start with 0, not one. And our computers do. And that way carda would line up with these values.

Also, if *r determines both the suit and the face value, what I said to change 80 to would not work.
*r = 0 gives ace of diamonds, *r = 1 gives ace of hearts, *r = 2 gives ace of clubs, *r = 3 gives ace of spades, *r = 4 gives two of diamonds, *r = 5 gives two of hearts, and so on.

Hope this helped. Good luck!